# not updating in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This is my code

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$short_content = $_POST['short_content'];
$long_content = $_POST['long_content'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$lang = $_POST['language'];
//echo $id." ".$category." ".$title." ".$short_content." ".$lang." ".$date;

if(empty($id)){
    echo "<h3 align=\"center\">Please fill ID</h3>";
}

if(empty($category)){
    echo "<h3 align=\"center\">Please fill Category</h3>";
}

if(empty($title)){
    echo "<h3 align=\"center\">Please fill Title</h3>";
}

if(empty($date)){
    echo "<h3 align=\"center\">Please fill Date</h3>";
}

if(empty($lang)){
    echo "<h3 align=\"center\">Please fill Lang</h3>";
}

if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
    $extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['img']['name']));
    //echo "file format: ".$extension."<br>";
    $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['img']['size'];

    if(file_exists("views/admin/uploads/".$name)){
        echo "<h3 align=\"center\">".$_FILES['img']['name']." exists</h3>
        <a href=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."><h3 align=\"center\">Go back</h3></a>";
        return false;
    }

    if($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif" && $extension != "JPG"){
        echo "<h3 align=\"center\">File with format: ".$extension." is not aviable to upload</h3>
        <a href=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."><h3 align=\"center\">Go back</h3></a>";
        return false;
    }
}

if(!empty($id) && !empty($category) && !empty($title) && !empty($date) && !empty($lang)){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `news` SET `id`='$id', category`='$category',`title`='$title',`img`='$name',`short_content`='$short_content',`content`='$long_content',`date`='$date',`lang`='$lang' WHERE `id`='$id'");
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"views/admin/uploads/".$name);
    echo "<h2 align=\"center\">Successfully updated!</h2>";
}
```

It's should update table row, but it dont. The input value are sending ok. Please give me a solution..

Which part of code is wrong?????

Comment: If you can make the code readable to humans I'm sure someone on here will have a clue

Comment: Can you even give your database dump?

Comment: Which echo is firing, `Successfully updated!` or one the errors?

Comment: Query looks ok but its very vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and also you're using the old mysql_ libs, these are deprecated and due to be removed in future php versions consider changing to mysqli or pdo.  Apart from that are you actually receiving your "Successfully updated!" alert is it even hitting that block of code ?

Comment: I wish PHP would dump the `mysql_*` calls already... all the SQL injections are making my head hurt :-/

Comment: Is this code present inside `function` because you have written `return false;` in your `if` condition. Also what output you are getting `Successfully updated!`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know will this fix your problem (yes, I don't have time to test this), but be happy about that I made your code much more readable.

In the future, it would be much easier answer if you **1. make your code readable** and **2. give your mysql database dump**.

Create `classes.php` file and add this code inside it. Change your host, dbname, username and password if needed.

```
// Connecting to database
class mysql{
    public $db;
    public function connect(){
        $this->db = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx;",
            "root",
            ""
        );
    }
}

// Update thing
class stuff extends mysql{
    public function updateThing($id,$cat,$title,$img,$shortContent,$content,$date,$lang){
        $this->statement = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `news` SET `category`= $2,`title` = $3,`img` = $4,`short_content` = $5,`content` = $6,`date` = $7,`lang` = $8 WHERE `id` = $1");
        $this->statement->execute(array($id,$cat,$title,$img,$shortContent,$content,date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date)),$lang));
        print_r($this->statement->fetchAll());
    }
}
```

And then throw these into file what updates things:

```
include_once("classes.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];
$cat = $_POST['category'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$shortContent = $_POST['short_content'];
$longContent = $_POST['long_content'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$lang = $_POST['language'];

$stuff = new stuff;
$stuff->connect();

$errors = array();

if(empty($id)){
    $errors[] = "Please fill ID";
}

if(empty($cat)){
    $errors[] = "Please fill Category";
}

if(empty($title)){
    $errors[] = "Please fill Title";
}

if(empty($date)){
    $errors[] = "Please fill Date";
}

if(empty($lang)){
    $errors[] = "Please fill Lang";
}

if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
    $extension = end(explode(".",$_FILES['img']['name']));

    $name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['img']['size'];

    if(file_exists("views/admin/uploads/".$name)){
        $errors[] = "File with this name already exists!";
    }

    if($extension != "jpg" && $extension != "png" && $extension != "gif" && $extension != "JPG"){
        $errors[] = "Unknown file format!";
    }
}

if(count($errors)==0){
    $stuff = new stuff;
    $stuff->connect();
    $stuff->updateThing($id,$cat,$title,$img,$shortContent,$longContent,$date,$lang);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"views/admin/uploads/".$name);

    echo "<h2>Successfully updated!</h2>";
}else{
    print "<h3>Errors!</h3><ul><li>".join("</li><li>",$errors)."</li></ul>";
}
```